# Can not modify property of an object

Tags: powershell

I have following file below which I read as Hashtable and need to modify value of a property but it fails to do so with error `InvalidOperation: The property 'apiVersion' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.`

Code

```bsh
$template = ConvertFrom-Json ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(".\template.json")) -AsHashtable; 
$template.resources.apiVersion = "d"
```

JSON file

```json
{
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2019-07-01"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Try `$template.resources[0].apiVersion = "d"` instead.

**Long Answer**

When you **read** the `apiVersion` using `$template.resources.apiVersion`, PowerShell does some magic for you to retrieve the value. However, when you try to **write** the value, PowerShell doesn't do the same magic and so you get the error you're seeing:

```bsh
PS> $json = @"
{
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2019-07-01"
    }
  ]
}
"@

PS> $data = $json | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable; 

PS> $data.resources.apiVersion  # powershell does some magic here
2019-07-01

PS> $data.resources.apiVersion = "d" # but doesn't do any magic here
InvalidOperation: The property 'apiVersion' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
```

This is because `$data.resources` is really an array containing a single item. To write *back* to the array you need to tell PowerShell which index in the array you want to update:

```
PS> $data.resources[0].apiVersion = "d"

PS> $data.resources.apiVersion # powershell does its magic again
d
```

Note you can *read* the value using the same syntax and avoid the need for PowerShell to do its magic:

```bsh
PS> $data.resources[0].apiVersion # no magic needed!
d
```

The "magic" that PowerShell is doing for you is called [Member Enumeration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/#member-enumeration) which is why `$template.resource.apiVersion` returns a value. When you reference a property on an array object (in your case `apiVersion`), PowerShell will iterate over all the objects in the array and collect their `apiVersion` values together.

However the same doesn't work for setting values - you need to specifically tell it which index in the array to update (in your case index 0 - i.e. `[0]`)...

Answer (score 1):

Since `Resources` is an array, denoted by the `[]` enclosure, you must go into the specific index that contains your sub-property.

```
# if you know the index (0 in your example)
$template.resources[0].apiVersion = 'd'

# if you do not know the index
($template.resources | where {$_.ContainsKey('apiVersion')}).apiVersion = 'd'
```